# Asp.net core mvc: when the client requests any view, how can the controller chooses the action method that will render the intended view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new in asp.net core mvc and as I understand that incoming requests are handled by controllers and the controller may has many action method as

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ViewResult RsvpForm()
{
    return View();
}
public ViewResult GuestsList()
{
    return View("Guests");
}
```

so when the client request any view how can the controller choose the action method that will render the intended view

Comment: That concept is called routing, and you can read about it in any basic ASP.NET MVC tutorial. Perhaps you should study those more carefully before asking a question here, so that you're not having all the basics spoonfed to you.

Comment: Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)